# which PATH environment does "exec env - " use?

Tags: linux, shell

please see two commands:

```
$ export PATH="/bin"

$ exec env - /bin/bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```

the result is :

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

why ?? how can I modify the PATH variable used in "exec env -"

Answer (score 3):

The `-` option to `env` clears the environment (therefore the exported `PATH` gets thrown away).  When `bash` starts up it will perform its normal startup file processing (which probably isn't very much since the `-c` option specifies a non-interactive shell).

So `bash` starts up with no `PATH` in its environment and likely doesn't get one set by a startup file, so it will use a default value.  I think that's what you're seeing.

If you're unable to modify the `env -` command (as you mention in some comments), then to get the `PATH` you want you'll need to convince `bash` to execute a startup file that sets the `PATH` to what you're looking for.

The following is an indication that you might be out of luck since I don't see any startup files being opened by `bash`:

```
$ (strace env - /bin/bash -c 'echo $PATH') 2>&1 | grep -E 'open|exec'
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "-", "/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $PATH"], [/* 48 vars */]) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $PATH"], [/* 0 vars */]) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)     = 3
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Comment: `-c` skips all file loading, except a file specified by the optional [BASH_ENV](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). Because of `env -`, that's out the window, so the OP is out of luck.

Comment: Good note about `BASH_ENV`.  `bash` startup processing is so convoluted and conditional that I didn't trust an assertion that no startup file processing is done in this case without evidence from `strace`.  I happened to have the diagrams from [this article](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html) open in another browser tab, and they aren't pretty.

Answer (score 1):

`env` runs a program in an *optionally modified* environment. By default, no modifications are made. To modify the environment, you can pass `-` (as your command does) or `-i` to remove all existing environment variables and start fresh, and/or pass key=value pairs on the command line to set new values. The latter is the situation you desire:

```
$ env - PATH="/bin" /bin/bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/bin
```

Per the man page:

> **NAME**
>          env - run a program in a modified environment
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>          `env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]`
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>          Set each NAME to VALUE in the environment and run COMMAND.

---

Since you cannot modify the command, and the command uses `-` to clear the environment, and the command is `bash -c` you are out of luck. Here's why:

`-c` means to execute the given string as a single command. In that mode, normal startup files are not executed. The only way to get a startup file executed in that mode is to [set the `BASH_ENV` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). However, that won't work in this case because of the `env -`, which clears all env.

Comment: I can not pass param to "exec env -" . is there any other ways ? for example : modify a bash_profile config file ?

Comment: Why can you not pass arguments to `env`? But, yes, add the line `PATH=/bin` to the top of your `.bashrc` to have that path used in the shell.

Comment: because the shell command is compiled into a binary jar file. I cound not modify it. and modify ".bashrc" is useless, you cound have a try...

Comment: So your _actual_ question is: how can I set PATH to a specific value when I have an `exec env` call like this and _I cannot modify that exec call_? What _can_ you modify? Like: can you modify the string passed to `bash -c`?

Comment: I guess I can modify some file , for example /etc/profile ?

Comment: Sorry, then, you are out of luck. See edit for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` you see is a **Bash variable** - not an **environment variable**.

We can demonstrate this using `printenv` or `export` (I've piped through `cut` to show just the names and not the values):

```
$ env - bash -c printenv | cut -d= -f1
PWD
SHLVL
_
```

There are many more (non-exported) Bash variables:

```
$ env - bash -c set | cut -d= -f1
BASH
BASHOPTS
BASH_ALIASES
BASH_ARGC
BASH_ARGV
BASH_CMDS
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING
BASH_LINENO
BASH_SOURCE
BASH_VERSINFO
BASH_VERSION
DIRSTACK
EUID
GROUPS
HOSTNAME
HOSTTYPE
IFS
MACHTYPE
OPTERR
OPTIND
OSTYPE
PATH
PPID
PS4
PWD
SHELL
SHELLOPTS
SHLVL
TERM
UID
_
```

(Note that with no `$HOME`, our user startup scripts are not run; you could add `--norc` to exclude `/etc/bash.bashrc` and the like, too).

---

If you use a different shell, you'll get a different set of default variables:

```
$ env - dash -c set | cut -d= -f1
IFS
OPTIND
PATH
PPID
PS1
PS2
PS4
PWD
```

```
$ env - dash -c printenv | cut -d= -f1
PWD
```